# Can a warehouse be virtual?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

I am trying to help a non-native colleague

We are talking about a stock inventory system, wherein there are 'warehouses' and 'warehouse groupings'

The goal is to name these 2 discrete entities as initutively as we can, so that a user can identify what exactly these entities are capable of and are not capable of

The problem statment was (paraphrasing):

> We are currently trying to name these 2 entities, and we think that we should call them 'warehouse and warehouse groups', however a 'warehouse' entity can sometimes represent a completely virtual location. We see that other systems try to use 'sources' to represent 'sources of stock'. We want to use 'warehouse' and 'warehouse groups' though, is there anything definitively wrong about this concept?

I then Googled the definition for '[warehouse](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/warehouse)', however [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/warehouse) is a bit more abstract. The definition does not explicitly say it could be imagined or non-tangible though.

So I then looked for '[repository](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repository)' and the definition seems 'perfect', but even to me this name seems a little far-fetched and non-intutitive.

Additionally, I referenced that the term '[data warehousing](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/1184/data-warehouse-dw)' exists.

On the whole is 'warehouse' the most appropriate word (considering 'source' was deemed out of the question), or is there another word I am missing?

Comment: You're asking "Can a warehouse be virtual?" in the title but then asking " is 'warehouse' the most appropriate word?" in the body. You don't actually state what a "warehouse" would represent in your stock inventory system. Does a virtual warehouse stock virtual products?

Comment: You need to figure out *why* they believe a warehouse can be virtual.   Maybe it’s simply a logical front-end to a very distributed  stock storage scheme such that there is no single building.   In a different line of thought if you define the operations a warehouse supports and then can show that whatever they have supports those operations then it seems like it could be called a warehouse.

Comment: @Jim I know the conceptual basis of this question, it is not a very distributed stock system. About operations performed being the basis of defining this, I could agree but I wanted to see some evidence for it ideally

Comment: @KillingTime I guess I forgot this point: yes a virtual warehouse stores virtual products, the term represents a store of stock either physical or virtual. A virtual warehouse stores virtual products, a physical warehouse stores physical products

Comment: Well,then a warehouse *can* be virtual.  For these virtual products- are they actually stored in quantity or are they just generated on demand?

Comment: @Jim The term is for assigning quantities of stock

Comment: I can tell you that the company I'm currently writing code for has "warehouses" which are just a concept, and in fact items from two different "warehouses" might be sitting on the same shelf in an actual, physical warehouse and be indistinguishable from each other.

Comment: Like Esther, I once worked with five warehouses, but 5 was only a database label for stuff like end-of-line items, and 4 was really a stack of shelves inside 3.

The map is not the road and the wares have no corporeal connection to the database, which is further from reality than an traditional paper inventory.

In software, can 'shelves' in 'warehouses' and 'warehouse groupings' on 'industrial estates' not be swapped for 'caches/stashes/heaps/piles/any term you like'?

Isn't half the point that giving 37 categories to the same item is a trivial act with phenomenal power?

Comment: I understand the point of the answer from @Esther, however I would say that the discussion has now strayed more into Software Design. And of course by this merit anything can be named *anything*, some lexical and keyword restrictions notwithstanding. I was intending to find out if Warehouse is the most intuitive word for a non-tangible store of stock

Comment: What do warehouses in a group have in common?  Is it that they all carry the same products?